# Punctuation makes entertainment go round

Tags: knowledge, wordplay

Find two sequences of letters (that may or may not be words) such that when

- the first sequence is repeated in each cell in column 1
- the second sequence is repeated in each cell of column 2

the results match the given descriptions.

| 1 |  | 2 | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | & |  | studio album |
|  | + |  | film |
|  | / |  | film |
|  | , |  | novel |
|  |  |  | magazine |

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think 1 and 2 are

> X and Y, respectively

Reasoning

> [X&Y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X%26Y) = studio album
>  [X+Y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X%2BY) = film
>  [X/Y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X/Y) = film
>  X,Y = novel by [Michael Blumlein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Blumlein)
>  [XY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_(magazine)) = magazine